# unmet dependencies for uuid-dev

Tags: 14.04, dependencies

I tried apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, apt-get install -f but still cannot get past this dependency.

I am running 14.04. How do I get rid of this so I can install uuid-dev.

```
$ sudo apt-get install uuid-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 uuid-dev : Depends: libuuid1 (= 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20) but 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on 14.04.
I was able to get this working by doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install libuuid1=2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20
sudo apt-get install libuuid-dev
```